# Snappy 15.04: How to install deb file? nano deb

Tags: dpkg, ubuntu-core

On `Snappy Ubuntu 15.04`: Linux localhost.localdomain 3.19.0-51-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:05:05 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu

With much pain, using curl.curl and moving of file, I was able to download the nano deb file.

However, when I tried to run 
`sudo dpkg -i nano_2.2.6-3_amd64.deb` it failed with error message
`dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system`

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Snappy Ubuntu Core is a read-only file system. It's based on snap and not on debs. It means that you can't install them on your system on purpose.

You can make a "nano" snap that you will install on your system. For more information on how to create snaps, here is the tour (do not hesitate to explore the developer website): https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/